# Installing the Java JDK on Windows 10 and Cygwin without admin permissions

Tags: java, cygwin, installation, admin-rights

I'm trying to install the Java JDK on Windows 10 and under the Unix-style Cygwin system. I don't have admin rights though. This limits install of both Cygwin and Java JDK.

(Existing solutions here only cover JDK without admin rights).

Update: 
I've found a way to do this, described in this helpful article: [Installing the Java JDK on Windows 10 without admin rights](https://tutorialgram.com/java/install-java-jdk-without-windows-10-admin-rights-cygwin/). Basically, you can install Cygwin without admin rights using "--no-admin", and then extract the JDK install executable to install manually, the JDK paths can then be setup. And Java compiler (javac) ran.

Comment: This question might be flagged as off-topic, would it be more suited to SO sibling site https://superuser.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

you can download zip file of jdk from below link:

https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp#win

After that set JAVA_HOME and PATH. It will work!!

Comment: The zip is an install executable which won't run, as admin rights are needed.